# How to rename legend and include color palette in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the labels of a legend. The plot has a color palette applied to it (palette npg). However, when I rename legend "10^7", "10^5", the color is reset to a default palette.

sample data set:

```
Concentration Strain Values1  
10000CFU F 0.01  
10000CFU F 0.03  
10000CFU F 0  
10000CFU M3 0.05  
10000CFU M3 0.03  
10000CFU M3 0  
10000CFU M5 0.02  
10000CFU M5 0.02  
10000CFU M5 0.01  
1000000CFU F 0.01  
1000000CFU F 0.02  
1000000CFU F 0.01  
1000000CFU M3 0.05  
1000000CFU M3 0.04  
1000000CFU M3 0.04  
1000000CFU M5 0.12  
1000000CFU M5 0.11  
1000000CFU M5 0.10
```

```
mydata <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


p <- ggboxplot(mydata, x = "Strain",  y = "Values1",palette="npg",fill="Concentration") + stat_compare_means(
    comparisons = list(c("thing1", "thing2")), 
    label = "p.signif", method="t.test") + 
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())  + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom") + labs(title="Title", x = "Type", y = expression('OD'[600])) + scale_fill_discrete(labels=c(expression('10'^7),expression('10'^5)))

print(p)
```

Is there a way to set a color palette as well as rename the legend? If I use the above code, I get the following graph:

[Graph with legend added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gelfd.png)

However, I want to use a different color palette (for example, palette npg). If I delete the code

```
scale_fill_discrete(labels=c(expression('10'^7),expression('10'^5)))
```

I get the graph:
[Graph without legend, with color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJRHb.png)

I am open to alternative methods to apply a color scheme to the graphs.. However, I have many graphs and would like to stay consistent.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I have updated the original post to include a more complete example. @user11937744

Comment: The `file.choose()` chooses the dataset in your folder.  I don't have access to your file

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your previous comment! Sorry about that. I have added a sample data set to the original post @user11937744

Comment: I see some values that are `M3`, `F5`. Is that correct or some paste issue

Comment: With your data, I got the graph using the code.  But, I don't find any issue.  What is the actual problem.  Can you update your post with the graph you got.  `when I rename legend "A^2", "B^2",`That code is not shown?

Comment: I have updated the post to include pictures of the problem   @user11937744